# Sending SMS does not work on all devices

Tags: android, smsmanager

Here is my code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

I tried it on an LG and it works perfectly, but on a Galaxy, it does not work.

What could be the problem? Maybe hardware?

Comment: Works just fine on my Galaxy. Are you sure your message isn't too long for the `sendTextMessage()` method?

Comment: Is the permission in the correct spot in the manifest? Are you importing the correct `SmsManager` class? Are you sure the number is correct? Which Android version are you testing on? How are you determining that it doesn't work? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are also getting messages or reading messages in you application. If so then please add following to your manifest also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```